# Multiple php files in dynamic gutenberg block

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I am using render.php file to render a custom block content. I want to include other php files inside the render.php file.

Does the @wordpress/create-block has the built-in bundling of the php files or I have to configure it?

For example, I have a RandomQuote.php in the src directory and in the render.php, I have

```
include 'RamdomQuote.php'
```

The RandmonQuote.php file is not copied to the build folder.

Comment: I don't believe it does. What bundling do you imagine needing? You should just be able to use includes as normal.

Comment: include and require. I tried but it does not copy the included files to the build folder.

Comment: The build command should have a `--webpack-copy-php` option to copy other PHP files: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#build

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.